# It, this and that in paragraphs - "that" or "this" first and then "it"?

Tags: pronouns

**Example 1**

> More and more people are discovering that Tai Chi is one of the most valuable forms of exercise. **This** has led to a big demand for classes. **It** will also promote the importance of physical health.

**Example 2**

> For many traditional football supporters, it is a problem that so many young girls and women attend football matches these days. **That** is a sexist attitude of course. **It** has pissed off many people.

**It, this and that in paragraphs**
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/it-this-and-that-in-paragraphs

The Cambridge page says both "this" and "that" refer to the whole things.

Is it a rule that "this" or "that" has to be used first, and then "it" can be used?

---

This article says usually this or that first, but I don't know if this rule applies to more abstract structures such as referring to the whole setnence or paragraph like in Examples 1 and 2.
https://englishhelponline.me/2017/05/31/the-difference-between-words-it-and-thisthat/

Comment: No. There is no rule about the sequence in which these words can be used.

Comment: One of examples cited from Cambridge Dic. has this *…It has pissed off many people….* Did you add this sentence yourself? Or did you find the original source? Because it's not in the CD excerpt.

Answer (score 1):

**this** can be either *anaphoric* (taking its meaning from, referring back to, something already mentioned) or *cataphoric* (referring to something that will be, is about to be, stated) ; **that** is anaphoric only.

> Gravity causes the apple to fall to the ground. This we know to be true.
>
> This we know to be true: gravity causes the apple to fall to the ground.
>
> Gravity causes the apple to fall to the ground. That we know to be true.

Ungrammatical:

> That <sup>no</sup> we know to be true: gravity causes the apple  to fall to the ground.

There are no such clear-cut rules regarding the sequence in which **this** and **it** may appear in a paragraph; it will depend on what you are saying, and how.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused about your examples. I do not see how they are related to my questions.

Comment: They are the only rules you need to worry about regarding **this** and **that** as pronouns. Your other concerns are imaginary. There is no "sequence" of appearance rule regarding **it** and either of them.  You could reverse the order of your penultimate and ultimate sentences without any problem.

Comment: I got it now. Sorry I am bad at retrieving implications. Thank you, mate.

Comment: I will accept 50% of the blame.  I often rely on others making the logical leap :-)  In fact, it's one of the most pleasurable things to observe. Mental fireworks.